# MYSQL remove hyphen then get first numbers of characters of current date

Tags: mysql, replace, substring

Just like the title described, I would like to get first numbers of characters (for example 6 characters) of current date without hyphens. Something like this:

```
2018-12-04 becomes 201812
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CURDATE(), "-", ""), 0, 6)
```

But returns empty. But when I do this, I get a result, which is 20181204:

```
REPLACE(CURDATE(), "-", "")
```

Is it not possible using nested mysql function like that? Are there any alternatives to that? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String positions in MySQL start at 1. So you actually need

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CURDATE(), "-", ""), 1, 6)
```

Comment: I completely forgot about "1" as first index in MySQL. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

For alternative, you can concatenate year and month parts of date like:

```
SELECT CONCAT( YEAR(CURDATE()), MONTH(CURDATE()) )
```

Comment: This is one of the best alternatives. Thanks for tip